# How Can I Execute a Code in A New Window (After Opening)?

Tags: javascript

Through my code I will open a new window and collect some text by double-clicking, the code is-

```
document.addEventListener('dblclick',function (event) {
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className);
var T= window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=500");
T.document.write(element[0].innerText.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));
},false);
```

Now I want to execute below code in `T` window-

```
window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text_1 = window.getSelection().toString();
        text = text_1
                .replace(/\n|\r/g, " ")
                .replace(/\s/, "");
      }
        words = text.split(" ");
        console.log(words);
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Above code will collect words , after selection by mouse using `window.getSelection().toString()`.

How can I do that ?

PS: This is not a duplicate question because both part will be in same script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `addEventListener` on `T` inside the `dblclick` event, and then instead of referring to `window` there, refer to `T`. And refer to `T.console` instead of just `console`:

```
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className);
  var T = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=500");
  T.document.write(element[0].innerText.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));

  T.addEventListener(
    "keydown",
    function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 16) {
        var text = "";
        if (T.getSelection) {
          text_1 = T.getSelection().toString();
          text = text_1
            .replace(/\n|\r/g, " ")
            .replace(/\s/, "");
        }
        words = text.split(" ");
        T.console.log(words);
      }
    },
    false
  );

}, false);
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2bw50zd/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should append a `script` node to your "MsgWindow"-window.

Edit (complete code):

Create new `script.js`-file with this code:

```
window.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 16) {
      var text = "";
      if (window.getSelection) {
        text_1 = window.getSelection().toString();
        text = text_1
                .replace(/\n|\r/g, " ")
                .replace(/\s/, "");
      }
        words = text.split(" ");
        console.log(words);
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Then the code, that is triggering a new window should look like this:

```
document.addEventListener('dblclick',function (event) {
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.className);
var T= window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=500");
T.document.write(element[0].innerText.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));
T.document.createElement('script');
script.src = *path to your script.js-file*;
T.document.head.appendChild(script);
},false);
```

Comment: @Mike, what is this link?

I'm talking about `document.createElement('script')`.

Comment: I request you to give the complete code using my parts given above

Comment: By the way your approach didn't work  for eample I gave ``script.src = "C:\Users\TTM\Desktop\selected_txt.js";`` are sure your approach works ?